# Why are new classes required to be subclass of something?

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I create a new class, I have to select what this new class is a subclass of.

**Why?**

Sometimes I just want a regular fresh class. I end up making it a subclass of `NSObject` (or anything) and just removing the `:NSObject` in the class declaration. But is there a reason behind requiring it at creation?

[image: With]
[image: Without]

Comment: Just choose new "Swift File" instead of "Cocoa Class"

Comment: It's also possible to create your own templates: http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating new classes with New -> "Cocoa Touch Class". Those classes are UI elements, which must inherit from `NSObject`. To create arbitrary classes without inheriting, just use New -> "Swift File" and write everything by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

When you add new file, on this screen:[image: Screenshot1]
chose Swift File:
[image: Screenshot2]
And write what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a class to be a subclass of any class, you can just create a swift file.

[image]